# How to check if a view is of an appropriate type before using in Adapter getView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, findviewbyid

I'm using [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) with 3 types of `Views`

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    //...
}
```

And it appears that sometimes wrong types of Views are passed to [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). Indeed docs warn about it:

> Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using.

**How should I check if a view is of an appropriate type before using?**

Should I just check by [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) if it contains some id from appropriate xml? But does it really check "if a view is of an appropriate type"?

EDIT: Answers so far seems to not miss my question so to clarify:
Yeah I'm using `getItemViewType` but as I have 3 types of Views, then sometimes `convertView` in [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) has wrong type (not the View which was inflated for the `getItemViewType`) and cannot be converted to the right one - the question is not about how to check which View SHOULD be returned (and this is covered by "bigdestroyer" answer), but if the View passed to getView can be reused (and in my case it cannot).

Comment: Well, if `convertView != null`, it can be reused. Why do you say that in your case it can't?

Comment: No because I'm getting wrong View as convertView. If you look on http://learnncode.co/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/ then for example for VIEW_TYPE_TEXT I'm getting R.layout.view_row_type_two instead of R.layout.view_row_type_one.

Comment: I understand now. That is strange, can you show all your adapter code?

Comment: Hah I probably know what's wrong, I'm using https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview not the stock Android ListView and it seems that it has this bug, anyway thanks  bigdestroyer because thanks to your hint I know I was doing right and it's someone else's fault :)

Comment: Nice! I hope you solve it ^^

Answer (score 2):

"Appropriate type" means that you have to check in `getView` method the type of the `convertView` in order to return a custom `View` or another one.

You can override `getItemViewType` method of `BaseAdapter`. For instance:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

      MyItem item = getItem(position);
      return item.getViewType();

}
```

and:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

     if (convertView != null) {

         if (viewType == 1) return recycleViewOfType1(position, convertView);
         if (viewType == 2) return recycleViewOfType2(position, convertView);

     }

     else {

         if (viewType == 1) return newViewOfType1(position);
         if (viewType == 2) return newViewOfType2(position);

     }

         return null;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getItemViewType()` method to determine view type before creating/ reusing views in `getView()` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
int type = getItemViewType(position);

if(type == 1){

}else {

}
}
```

check [this](http://learnncode.co/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/) tutorial for more info

Comment: you can check my edit on question because I think this is not the answer